# Sorting JSON values by field type in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
attribute
id          project_id  name          type
"556e28ab"  "14b106fd"  "running_id"  "INTEGER"
"7c78e6a4"  "14b106fd"  "headline"    "TEXT"

record
id          project_id  data
"63d7af84"  "14b106fd"  "{""headline"": ""Mike Tyson set to retire after loss"", ""running_id"": 0}"
"055e85ff"  "14b106fd"  "{""headline"": ""Iraqi vote remains in doubt"", ""running_id"": 1}"
"2dd0acdc"  "14b106fd"  "{""headline"": ""Conservatives Ponder Way Out of Wilderness"", ""running_id"": 2}"
"d8b82916"  "14b106fd"  "{""headline"": ""Final report blames instrument failure for Adam Air Flight 574 disaster"", ""running_id"": 3}"
"a71268cf"  "14b106fd"  "{""headline"": ""Kim Sets a Skating Record and Wins Her First World Title"", ""running_id"": 4}"
```

I want to sort values by `running_id`, inside the data `json`. If I do this, the sort will be considering `running_id` as an `STRING` and not as `INTEGER`, as it should be.

```
SELECT *
FROM record r
WHERE r.project_id = '14b106fd'
ORDER BY (r.data ->>'running_id') ASC;
```

I could cast it to `INTEGER`, but that is not a good solution because I want to be able to order by any field inside the `json` and these fields are not defined by me. I would like to find a way to cast it without explicitly defining the type or using the type from the `attribute` table, which I already tried but it is interpreted as `STRING` and not as a `type`.

I also already tried the following code:

```
SELECT r.*, a.data_type
FROM record r
JOIN attribute a ON (a.name = 'running_id' AND a.project_id = r.project_id)
WHERE r.project_id = '14b106fd'
ORDER BY
    CASE CAST(a.data_type AS TEXT)
        WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN CAST(r.data ->> 'running_id' AS INTEGER)
        WHEN 'NUMERIC' THEN CAST(r.data ->> 'running_id' AS NUMERIC)
        ELSE r.data ->>'running_id'
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have another json field `running_txt`, which is of json string data type. You want to sort by either `running_id` or `running_txt`

- sort by `running_id` as integer data type:

```sql
select id,
       project_id,
       data
  from ibiscp_record
 order by case when json_typeof(data->'running_id')='number' then cast(data->>'running_id' as integer) end , data->>'running_id';
```

Outcome:

```
id      |project_id|data                                                                                                                        |
--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
63d7af84|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Mike Tyson set to retire after loss", "running_id": 0, "running_txt": "0"}                                    |
2dd0acdc|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Conservatives Ponder Way Out of Wilderness", "running_id": 2, "running_txt": "2"}                             |
d8b82916|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Final report blames instrument failure for Adam Air Flight 574 disaster", "running_id": 3, "running_txt": "3"}|
a71268cf|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Kim Sets a Skating Record and Wins Her First World Title", "running_id": 4, "running_txt": "4"}               |
055e85ff|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Iraqi vote remains in doubt", "running_id": 11, "running_txt": "11"}                                          |
```

- sort by `running_txt` as string data type (need to change json field name from `running_id` to `running_txt`, the rest query remains unchanged)

```sql
select id,
       project_id,
       data
  from ibiscp_record
 order by case when json_typeof(data->'running_txt')='number' then cast(data->>'running_txt' as integer) end , data->>'running_txt';
```

Result:

```
id      |project_id|data                                                                                                                        |
--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
63d7af84|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Mike Tyson set to retire after loss", "running_id": 0, "running_txt": "0"}                                    |
055e85ff|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Iraqi vote remains in doubt", "running_id": 11, "running_txt": "11"}                                          |
2dd0acdc|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Conservatives Ponder Way Out of Wilderness", "running_id": 2, "running_txt": "2"}                             |
d8b82916|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Final report blames instrument failure for Adam Air Flight 574 disaster", "running_id": 3, "running_txt": "3"}|
a71268cf|14b106fd  |{"headline": "Kim Sets a Skating Record and Wins Her First World Title", "running_id": 4, "running_txt": "4"}               |
```